# Javascript: $(window).scroll, $ not defined

Tags: javascript, function, scroll

I'm pretty new at Javascript and I'm following some code from Code Pen to try and create a shadow effect underneath the nav bar when the page is scrolled. The code looks like this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('#navBar').addClass('floatingNav');
  } else {
    $('#navBar').removeClass('floatingNav');
  }
});
```

When I run this though, the console returns this error (in reference to the first line):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this. I've seen plenty of examples in other people's code where $(window).scroll works fine. Is there a way to define it? Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to add the jQuery library to your document: http://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Did you include `jQuery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the jQuery framework for the $ to work. the $ symbol here denotes that jquery framework is used. add the following line above your `<script>` tag and run it again.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```